# How to check if a column with a given name exists in a datarow

Tags: vb.net, datarow

I want to insert a value from loop in datarow so before entering value in datarow, I want to check that a perticular column NAME exist in table or not. 
Please tell me how can I check it. (vb.net preferred).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the answer.and its working . its:

```
  If dr.Table.Columns.Contains("columnname") = True Then
   --your work---
  End If
```

Comment: This part of statement  `= True`  is not necessary. The contains method return a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
    If dc.ColumnName = "" Then

    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
if dr.Table.Columns("nameColumn") == null then

 //....
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest solution.

```
 If dr.Table.Columns.Contains("columnname") Then
     'your code here
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to find out if a column exists:

```
If dataRow.Table.Columns("ColumnName") IsNot Nothing Then
    -- Your code if a column exists
End If
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077498/3345644) for further reference when this approach might be handier than the `Contains("ColumnName")` one.